# Possible to find $E(X)$ given $f_{\alpha}(x \mid z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\alpha_{0}-\alpha_{1} z\right)^{2}}$

Tags: statistics

$f_{\alpha}(x \mid z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\alpha_{0}-\alpha_{1} z\right)^{2}}$ is the density of a normal distributed random variabel. Is it possible to find the expectation $E(X)$ from this density? Notice that $f_\alpha$ is the conditional density of $X$ given $Z=z$.

Comment: To the person who down voted the question; why? If you don't understand my question, then just ask.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible without knowing the expected value of $Z$. $$\begin{align}E(X)&=E\left(E(X|Z)\right)\\
&=E(\alpha_0+\alpha_1 Z)\\
&=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 E(Z)\end{align}$$

If $Z$ is standard normal, then $E(X)=\alpha_0$.